# How should I download a file in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, download, callback

I need my Node script to download a file, run a test on the file, and then depending on the result, download some more files and run some more code. It seems that the only way I can do this is to have a complicated series of nested callback functions. Is there really not a simpler way?

Comment: Promises and async/await will do the trick :)

Comment: [Request](https://github.com/request/request) makes this pretty easy.